# Updating Images in PageViewer Dynamically

Tags: java, android

I can get the images that are specified in my `images[]` array to display correctly when I load the fragment but once I have updated the `images[]` array I am unable to subsequently update the ImageViews in the ViewPager.

What is the best approach for doing so?

Here is my instantiating code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_forsale_photos, null);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivViewPagerForsalePhoto);

    try {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(images[position])
                .into(imageView);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Glide error " + e);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter should return `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` in `getItemPosition`. With that you can trigger `notifyDataSetChanged` to reload changes.

Check with debugger if `instantiateItem` is triggered after this change. Also validate if Glide is not loading images from cache.

Comment: many thanks for that reply. When I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` I get a thread exception: `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`.

Comment: I have fixed the above issue by using `onPostExectute` to run `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the UI thread.